# How do you load every PictureBox on a form into an array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm currently trying to find a way to change every PictureBox on my form to have the same image.
I have achieved this, but its messy, and I was wondering if there is a 'cleaner' way to do this (As I will need to dynamically fill the PictureBox array later on in my project).

```vb
Dim pbxCollection() As PictureBox = {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4, PictureBox5, PictureBox6, PictureBox7, PictureBox8, PictureBox9} 'collection of all pictureboxes

For Each pbx In pbxCollection 'iterates through the PictureBox array and changes each value
   pbx.Image = My.Resources.<image file name here>
Next
```

The above code does what I want, but as you can see, I have 9 PictureBoxes. In future I will need to have any number of PictureBoxes up to 50, so this solution will no longer work then.

If there is a way to fill an array with every PictureBox on a form, I will be extremely grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an array, use an `IEnumerable`:

```
Dim pbxCollection = MyForm.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
```

Of course this is not recursive, so if there's a panel or group box you want to account for use that instead of `MyForm`. Also, make sure you run it *after* the `InitializeComponent()` method.

---

From the comments:

> I'm using a `tableLayoutPanel`

So assuming a name of `tableLayoutPanel1`, it might look something like this:

```
Dim pbxCollection = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
```

Comment: I am using a *tableLayoutPanel*  - I added this in as above, however there was a casting error:
 `'Unable to cast object of type '<OfTypeIterator>d__61'1[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox]' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[]'.'`
The component has been initialized, so this is not the issue. I'm still using the same `for loop`, is it an error in my code?

Comment: @JoeMoore, the instruction is right but the code isn't quite. `Dim pbxCollection() As PictureBox` should be `Dim pbxCollection As IEnumerable(Of PictureBox)` or simply `Dim pbxCollection`.